# Django DRF: Name returned objects dynamically

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am not sure if a [dynaimc serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290390/list-serializer-with-dynamic-fields-in-django-rest-framework) is what I need, as I did not exactly understand when to use it. Following problem:

My serializer returns a working/valid json, but in a suboptimal shape:

```
[
    {
        "store": {
            "last_update": "2021-06-01T12:06:00Z",
            "store_id": 238,
        }
    },
    {
        "store": {
            "last_update": null,
            "store_id": 1,
            }
        }
    }
]
```

where I would want it to be:

```
[
    {
        "store_id": 238,
        "data": {
            "last_update": "2021-06-01T12:06:00Z",
        }
    },
    {
        "store_id": 1,
        "data": {
            "last_update": null,
        }
    }
]
```

simple model:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.IntegerField("store id", null = True, blank = True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField("last update")
```

serializer:

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    store = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_info")

    def get_info(self, store):
        tmp = {}
        tmp["store_id"] = store.store_id
        tmp["last_update"] = store.last_update
        return tmp

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ["store"]
```

views:

```
class StoreViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = StoreSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head']

    def list(self, request):
        try:
            query = Store.objects.all()
            results = StoreSerializer(data = query, many = True)
            results.is_valid()
            return Response(data = results.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as E:
            return Response(data = str(E), status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How can I alter the serializer to achieve the desired shape of the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Serializer will give the desired output:

```py
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_data(self, store):
        return {
          "last_update": store.last_update
        }

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ["store_id","data"]
```